# What Are The Main Differences Between Nvidia Different GPUs?

Tags: graphics-cards, nvidia

I am not asking about specific GPUs. Instead, I am asking about the difference between the GPU models themselves.

Example: `(RTX 3060, RTX 3060 Ti, Quadro RTX 2000, RTX A2000)`.

I could not find a focused and neat answer over the Internet. Almost all sites focus on specific models GPU comparisons with too technical details.

So, What are the differences, and what is better for what?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the first two and last two (Geforce and Quadro) are the drivers. Geforce drivers are more focused on shaders in games, while Quadro drivers are mostly focused on CUDA work like Blender.

With the GPU models you have listed, with the Quadro cards the main difference is the architecture (RTX 2000 uses Turing from 3/4 years ago, RTX A2000 uses Ampere from 1/2 years ago) and with the Geforce cards it's the target price point (RTX 3060 around €350, RTX 3060ti around €450).

Performance and specs wise, I can go into those like most sites on the internet do, but I won't since it maybe is too technical. I have made a comparison on hardware.info for the technical dudes out here: https://be.hardware.info/vergelijking/producten/594477-600417-627686-390937

Comment: What I meant was the difference function-wise. for example, gaming, video editing, and CADs. etc. Why a laptop GPU like RTX A5500 is notably more expensive than the laptop GPU RTX 3080 Ti, although some websites say that the latter is better in performance tests? Are they right? if Yes, What is the added value functionality that the user get and pay for?

Comment: The only added value is driver support and optimization for """professional""" software like CAD. Even then, the much better raw performance you get with a "gaming" RTX for the same price usually makes up for the better drivers on the Quadro/A-models.

Personally: Quadro has always been pointless and an utter waste of money.

Comment: The differences are physical/firmware too, not just drivers; Quadros have ECC RAM when GeForces usually do not. Some Quadro cards have SDI video ports, and also support for more than 4 screens to drive video walls. The GeForce cards are often pre-overclocked and get a custom cooler design. The remote management and virtualization functions are disabled on a GeForce, which is done to force businesses to buy a Quadro for most server and VM use cases. I suspect that GeForce cards also get premium/excessive power delivery components for the overclocking too.

Comment: Note that mobile GeForce/Quadro do not really see some of those differences I pointed out. ECC RAM and better features for virtual machines are the major differences you'd see on the mobile side.

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking about the difference between the GPU models themselves

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units

> Example: (RTX 3060, RTX 3060 Ti, Quadro RTX 2000, RTX A2000).

That's somewhat broad, best I can tell u keeping it pity...

- *Personally: Quadro has always been pointless and an utter waste of money.*  This is a fairly accurate statement, because Geforce and Quadro are the same piece of gpu hardware it is the firmware difference that's loaded into the chip making the difference; quadro has different features (not necessarily better) activated within it via firmware whereas geforce simply has them disabled, this had been discovered years ago.  I have never seen ior heard of a legitimate case where a quadro was needed where a geforce could not suffice.
- refer to wiki link for micro architecture history, it goes from ~2007 Tesla, Fermi, Kepler, Maxwell, Pascal, Volta, Turing, Ampere, Hopper
- **RTX** : models prior to the introduction to the *RTX* branding did not have *Ray Tracing*... https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/everything-you-need-to-know-about-nvidias-rtx-dlss-technology/
- hard to distinguish from documentation but nvidia lineup has a (roughly speaking) data center (gpgpu), desktop/workstation, and mobile.  The mobile or laptop are lower powered (less heat) and possibly smaller footprint versions of the desktop chips; obviously desktop/workstation style are on pcie cards that are fairly large with big fans which would never fit in a laptop; data center or gpgpu don't have graphics output they are purely for computational work.
- `3060 vs 3060TI` = *titanium* and per wiki you will see its a higher performing card from the base model but on the same architecture... https://www.cgdirector.com/ti-meaning-gpu/
- check out videocardbenchmark.net and look at the nvidia listings